# Get rid of extra gutter spacing

Tags: line-numbers

Vim always has 3 spaces for the line numbers on the left, in the gutter.  Since I `set relativenumber`, and (unfortunately) don't have a monitor with the vertical space for 100 lines, I will never need more than 2 places for the line number.  The leftmost column is always an extra space.

How can I reclaim that valuable screen real estate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim automatically sets the gutter spacing, but it has some constraints.  Notably, `numberwidth` determines the minimum number of columns reserved for the gutter.  The default is 4, 3 for the numbers and 1 for the space separating the numbers from the text.  That's one too many in this case, so `set numberwidth=3` in your vimrc, and you should be good to go.

Additionally, if you want 80 columns of text in your gvim windows, `set columns=83` will give you 2 line numbers, 1 space, and 80 columns.